# C# check for duplicate entry, then run insert query if no duplicates

Tags: c#, mysql

Hey guys i need help on this one. What I'm trying to do here is to check my mysql db if a member already exists using the name of the member based on the data entry on my winform. The verification for duplicate entry works, shows the messagebox perfectly the way i want, but it doesn't execute the insert query i made in case no existing member is found.

Am I doing this correctly? or is there another way to get it working the way i want.

Here is my code:

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    using (con = new MySqlConnection(constring)) {      
        string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM sbis.sb_members WHERE lname ='" + this.lnametxtbox.Text + "' AND fname = '" + this.fnametxtbox.Text + "' AND mname ='" + this.mnametxtbox.Text + "'  ";
        MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, con);

        string insertquery = "INSERT INTO sbis.sb_members (lname, fname, mname, position, appointment, address, contactnum, birthdate, civilstatus, educattainment, eligibility, terms_idterms, polparties_id, sex) VALUES (@lname, @fname, @mname, @position, @appointment, @address, @contactnum, @birthdate, @civilstatus, @educattainment, @eligibility, @terms_idterms, @polparties_id, @sex)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertquery, con);
        string lname, fname, mname, address, contactnum, educattainment;

        lname = lnametxtbox.Text;
        fname = fnametxtbox.Text;
        mname = mnametxtbox.Text;
        address = addresstxtbox.Text;
        contactnum = contacttxtbox.Text;
        educattainment = eductxtbox.Text;
        var birthdate = birthdatedtp.Value.Date;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", mname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnum", contactnum);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", position);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointment", appointment);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", sex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eligibility", eligibility);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@civilstatus", civilstatus);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terms_idterms", terms);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@polparties_id", polparties);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@educattainment", educattainment);

        try {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader cr = command2.ExecuteReader();
            while (cr.Read()) {
                if (cr.HasRows == true) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Member already exists.", "Duplicate Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                } else if (cr.HasRows == false) {
                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {
                        MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
            cr.Close();     
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to know how to use prepared statements. So it's a mystery why are using string concatenation in your SELECT

```
string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM sbis.sb_members WHERE lname ='" + this.lnametxtbox.Text + "' AND fname = '" + this.fnametxtbox.Text + "' AND mname ='" + this.mnametxtbox.Text + "'  ";
```

But the good news is that you don't need this SELECT at all. You can just throw it away. And make use of the IGNORE feature in mysql. Or if you want to display that member already exists message, just catch the exception!

```
 using (con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {

        string insertquery = "INSERT INTO sbis.sb_members (lname, fname, mname, position, appointment, address, contactnum, birthdate, civilstatus, educattainment, eligibility, terms_idterms, polparties_id, sex) VALUES (@lname, @fname, @mname, @position, @appointment, @address, @contactnum, @birthdate, @civilstatus, @educattainment, @eligibility, @terms_idterms, @polparties_id, @sex)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertquery, con);
        string lname, fname, mname, address, contactnum, educattainment;


        lname = lnametxtbox.Text;
        fname = fnametxtbox.Text;
        mname = mnametxtbox.Text;
        address = addresstxtbox.Text;
        contactnum = contacttxtbox.Text;
        educattainment = eductxtbox.Text;
        var birthdate = birthdatedtp.Value.Date;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", mname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnum", contactnum);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", position);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointment", appointment);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", sex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eligibility", eligibility);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@civilstatus", civilstatus);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terms_idterms", terms);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@polparties_id", polparties);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@educattainment", educattainment);

        try
        {
             if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
             {
                   MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("duplicate key"))
             {
                    MessageBox.Show("Member already exists.", "Duplicate Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
             }
             else {
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The above example catches the duplicate key error to display the message that the user exists rather that ignoring errors.

Of course all this assumes that you have created a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the column that you do not want duplicated. That's a fundamental part of database design. And the standard practice is to rely on the database to enforce uniqueness and other constraints rather than doing it at the application level

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried the INSERT IGNORE, but I still get duplicate entries every time I save..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: glad to have been of help all the best with your project

Answer (score 0):

The `while (cr.Read())` is the problem, if the (read) table is empty (no duplicate), the loop never runs.

But the approach is bad because You have race conditions. What if someone inserts row after You checked that there is none? To really enforce the constraint, just add

```
ALTER TABLE sbis.sb_members ADD UNIQUE (lname, fname, mname)
```

Now You are safe from duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, really appreciate it.